Product description is wrapped in <div data-content-type="html" data-appearance="default" data-element="main" data-decoded="true"> - why?
Magento 2.4.6
When I am getting the product description programmatically using getDescription(), the description is wrapped in <div data-content-type="html" data-appearance="default" data-element="main" data-decoded="true">.
I suspect its related to the pagebuilder, but how can I avoid that? It does not happen for all products. My code is like this:
$desc = $product->getDescription();

And the result looks like that:
<div data-content-type="html" data-appearance="default" data-element="main" data-decoded="true">
    my description
</div>

The wrapping div can not be seen when opening the description of the product. So, how can this be avoided? I know there are similar questions out there, but no real answers :).
Thanks!

Did you checked in db ?

Try this for get an actual product description without HTML tags :
$content= $product->getDescription();
$clean_content = strip_tags(html_entity_decode($content));
